# RPA Automation anywhere using Reply Email by tracking the original email(email body as arguments, Cc copy)

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

RPA Automation anywhere using Reply Email by tracking the original email(email body as arguments, Cc copy)

sending or reply mail using create contents both in html and plain text

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Please read [ask] then [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: Let us know if you are using any email clients for replying. Also let us know how are you planning to pass the content for reply.